# Puppet: Move file to a different location based on the existence of a directory

Tags: puppet

I have this configuration:

```
file { 
     "/tmp/apc.ini":
     source => "puppet:///modules/uc/php/apc.ini",
     require => Package["php-apc"]
  } 

  exec {
    "Add apc.ini to php mods-available":
    command => 'mv /tmp/apc.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/apc.ini',
    onlyif =>  "test -d /etc/php5/mods-available",
    require => File["/tmp/apc.ini"]
  }

  exec { 
    "Add apc.ini to php conf.d":
    command => 'mv /tmp/apc.ini /etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini',
    unless =>  "test -d /etc/php5/mods-available",
    require => File["/tmp/apc.ini"]
  }
```

I'd like to be able to simplify this so that the /tmp/apc.ini file isn't created every time I run `puppet agent --test`

For the moment, I get the following output:

```
info: Retrieving plugin
info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/concat_basedir.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/postgres.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
info: Caching catalog for frontapp0.demo.infra.universcine.com
info: Applying configuration version '1376302253'
notice: /Stage[main]/Uc::Role::Php/File[/tmp/apc.ini]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}e5f5a158bd83469ce031b20ec72ce717'
notice: /Stage[main]/Uc::Role::Php/Exec[Add apc.ini to php mods-available]/returns: executed successfully
notice: Finished catalog run in 36.12 seconds
```

What can I try ?

**UPDATE** The goal is to have apc.ini either in mods-available or in conf.d, depending on whether the former exists or not

Comment: Why don't you just `require => File["/etc/php5/mods-available"]` and deploy apc.ini directly to the correct destination? Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry, I didn't read the `unless` in the second exec statement.

Comment: No problem, I really should have explained a bit more... I did in the update §

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish this would be to deploy a custom fact.  If you're using the `puppet-stdlib` module, you can write custom facts in the language of your choice by dropping an executable script into `/etc/facter/facts.d` (see [this article](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html) for details).  For example, if you created a script `/etc/facter/facts.d/apc_ini_path` with the following contents (and made sure it was executable):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -d /etc/php5/mods-available ]; then
  echo "apc_ini_path=/etc/php5/mods-available"
else
  echo "apc_ini_path=/etc/php5/conf.d/"
fi
```

Then you would have available a fact "apc_ini_path", and you could do this:

```
file { "$apc_ini_path/apc.ini":
    source => "puppet:///modules/uc/php/apc.ini",
    require => Package["php-apc"]
}
```

Of course, if you're comfortable with Ruby you can also just drop a Ruby fact into `YOURMODULE/lib/facter/yourfact.rb` using the examples presented [in the same article](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html).  They provide a sample Ruby fact that's pretty trivial:

```
# hardware_platform.rb

Facter.add("hardware_platform") do
  setcode do
    Facter::Util::Resolution.exec('/bin/uname -i')
  end
end
```

It should be fairly easy to replace this with a directory existence check.

Comment: looks good, I'll test this soon